# docker-compose command not available for mac

Tags: macos, docker, docker-compose, pyenv

I installed docker with the instructions here, downloading from docker-hub

```
https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/install/
```

But when I run `docker-compose` I get this error

```
pyenv: docker-compose: command not found

The `docker-compose' command exists in these Python versions:
3.6.5/envs/myenv
```

Also, docker-compose is available under /Users

```
which docker-compose
/Users/<username>/.pyenv/shims/docker-compose
```

In this link says, docker-compose for mac need not be installed explicitly as it is part of docker for desktop mac.

```
https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/
```

Is something wrong with my installation?

Comment: You also need to actually launch the "whale" application; some tools don't actually get installed until it starts up the first time.

Comment: @RonvanderHeijden Yes, I do have, but that isn't the official Docker suggested way. Would installation from brew makes sure I get all features, like connecting to kubernates etc.

Comment: @DavidMaze -  Whale? I donot have that, could you send some links to get it up.

Comment: If you've installed Docker for Mac (either via Homebrew or by downloading the installer yourself as per your link) there will be a "Docker" application in your Applications folder or the OS X Launchpad; it is circular, with a whale, with containers on its back.  Start that application and the whale icon should appear in the menu bar.  The first-time setup also adds some additional command-line tools and I think `docker-compose` is among those.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

I ran into the same issue on macOS today. ***Turned out that you need to run the installed app once***, it does some additional downloading and setup. That setup includes setting up your path variables.

Answer (score 46):

docker-compose is a utility that is now a parameter in mac docker
so instead of `docker-compose up`, its now `docker compose up`

Comment: Mickey,  using docker compose solved the issue for me. It's slightly odd. Do you have any documentation or any further read I can have on this. It will be useful.

Comment: lmgtfy - https://collabnix.com/docker-compose-now-shipped-with-docker-by-default/

Comment: This should be the accepted answer now.

Comment: thank you my friend. no hyphen worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

This following steps worked for me:

1. Install Docker Desktop as recommended.
2. Run Docker Desktop.
3. Go to Settings > Advanced Settings
4. Check how Docker's CLI tools are installed and make sure they are in the right `PATH`.
5. Under 'Choose how to configure the installation of Docker's CLI tools', I selected 'System' so that Docker CLI tools are installed under `/usr/local/bin`. Otherwise, follow the directions for the 'User' option (Docker CLI tools are installed under `$HOME/.docker/bin`.

Note: You need to manually add `$HOME/.docker/bin` to your environment variable PATH

Answer (score 4):

### Update Sept23: You need to install `docker` and `docker-compose` as CLI.

Ideally, it can be done by installing Docker Desktop but **[Desktop is not free](https://www.docker.com/pricing/)** & if you are using a company machine better check with tech ops first before installing it on your machine.

However, you can simply use `brew` on macOS to install both `docker` and `docker-compose` as I am describing here:

Run commands:

```
brew install docker

brew install docker-compose
```

Check the location where the `docker-compose` is installed:

```
which  docker-compose
```

It should return

> /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

Now make `docker-compose` executable to run it from the Terminal :

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

That's it!! now you compose images via the terminal.

Answer (score 2):

For the Docker desktop app on OSX go to `settings -> advanced` and change from the User CLI installation to the system settings then click `Apply and restart`

[image: Screenshot of correct Docker settings to apply]

Answer (score 1):

if you install docker from official website then docker-compose will come along with that for mac so need to either upgrade and documentation is present there.

Comment: You need to run the GUI at least once after install. Otherwise the command line tools never get set up properly. (MacOS Ventura 13.1)